# What does 'sudo -iu someusername' mean? What does it mean for scp-ing files up?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I'm having a communication problem with my IT department, and as a newb with terminal, this is really frustrating because I can't understand why I'm doing the things I'm instructed to do. All they're telling me is that I *have* to do it.

I have a server that I ssh into as anyone would: `ssh myname@thehost` and I enter my password.

This is where I get confused: IT told me that now I have to run this command: `sudo -iu otherusername`.

While I have looked up what those options `-iu` are (so I know that it's a "simulated initial login" -- whatever that means -- as this `otherusername`), but I don't *actually* understand what they mean or why I have to do this. So, my first question is, why do you think I have to do this? Why would one run such a command?

My next question is, how do I upload files to this server given that I have to log in as a different user after the initial login? I haven't tried, but can I simply `scp thefile myname@thehost:theDirectory`? How do I know which files are shared?

Sorry if these questions are especially newb. Gotta start somewhere, right? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo -iu <username>` logs you in as <username>, without having to know <username>'s password.

You have to be on the sudoers list for this to work, but if your IT department is asking you to do this, you presumably already are.

If you scp files to the server they will end up owned by the initial user, so you may have to move them to the correct location (and perhaps re-`chown` them) afterwards.

Comment: doesn't the `-i` implicate the use of the defined login-shell (from `/etc/passwd`), and thus the execution of specific ressource files such as `.profile` as well?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to summarise by saying "logs you in". Without -i you don't get a shell and you will need to specify a command for sudo to run.